# Websocket and Safari 6.0

Tags: safari, websocket

I am using Safari 6 and websockets. My server is receiving the following handshake from the browser:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: nomad.local:1299
Origin: file://
Sec-WebSocket-Key: WhZTuybN4i2ZshDBxco42w==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
```

There is no Protocol included. My server can deal with that, but when it tries to complete the handshake with the browser client I get the following message:
Error during WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Protocol mismatch

Is there an implied Protocol in the message sent to server that I need to return in the handshake to the client?

This worked before I upgraded to latest Safari

Comment: Can you add the response your server sends to your question please?  I presume the problem is as suggested by kanaka but it'd be good to be sure

Answer (score 1):

If the client does not send any sub-protocols in the handshake (Sec-WebSocket-Protocol) then the server must not send back a sub-protocol header (Sec-WebSocket-Protocol). If the server sends back the common default of "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat" even though the client did not include a sub-protocol header, the client must refuse the connection. Some browsers were sloppy about this and have recently begun to tighten up their compliance.

If the client does send a sub-protocol list, then the server must select a single sub-protocol that it supports and send this back to the client as the chosen sub-protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Well the protocol is WebSockets ;-) See the RFC for further explanations on Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6455/?include_text=1

The handshake from the client looks as follows:

```
    GET /chat HTTP/1.1
    Host: server.example.com
    Upgrade: websocket
    Connection: Upgrade
    Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
    Origin: http://example.com
    Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
    Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

The handshake from the server looks as follows:

```
    HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
    Upgrade: websocket
    Connection: Upgrade
    Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
    Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
```

Don't know wether the Safari 6 implemenation differs, but protocols from RFC are usually a nightmare... There might be a standard implied?